# Unable to get pod metrics -Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, autoscaling, horizontal-scaling, kubernetes-pod

I'm not able to get the metrics for the pod. The result for "describe hpa " command is shown below. I can not autoscale!!!

[image: result for describe hpa command]
my kubernetes version and result for "get hpa" is given in this screenshot below.
[image] 
Please help me to autoscale my app. I used this instruction to install hpa https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#run-expose-php-apache-server][3](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#run-expose-php-apache-server). I'm using digital ocean cloud to run my cluster.Help me install anything to get metrics so I can use that to hpa.

Comment: We need more information, please provide Kubernetes version and what is your environment - is it GKE? as it seems you used this [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#run-expose-php-apache-server). If yes on which step are you getting this error? also `kubectl get hpa` could be useful.

Comment: Can you post the output for `kubectl logs <heapster-pod>`?

Comment: is the heapster running?

Comment: yes @Rico heapster is running

Comment: I will check it on DigitalOcean, untill then check if this [issue](https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/issues/150)  on github explains your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to recreate this issue.

Digital Ocean does not support Cluster Auto scaling as mentioned [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/kubernetes/overview/). But it seems that HPA should work, as it scales pods.

I was able to work with this and get the HPA to work. Note that I did not spend a significant amount of time on this, so I am not yet aware if there are any issues later on. My goal was to make hpa scale and this was successful.

First install the [Metrics server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server) as the Heapster is deprecated. I did that by git clone and then `kubectl create -f deploy/1.8+/`.

Next find the metrics server deployment and edit it:

`kubectl edit deployment metrics-server -n kube-system`

Under `spec:` ->`containers:` add following metrics:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /metrics-server
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
        - --logtostderr
```

Wait few minutes, when you will call `kubectl get hpa` you will see that under TARGETS`<unknown>/50%`changes to `0%/50%` you are ready to generate the load and scale the pods. After you stop the load, the hpa will slowly start removing the pods.

UPDATE:

you probably missed a dash. It should look like this.

```
spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /metrics-server
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
        - --logtostderr
        image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.1
```

Delete the dash that was in front of "image".

Hope this helps.

Comment: i cannot save the deployment file after editing. saying `error: deployments.extensions "metrics-server" is invalid` @aurelius

Comment: updated the answer, the reason of the error was due to additional dash in wrong place after the edit.